# Backbone Change Event won't update View

Tags: backbone.js

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this darn view won't update when performing a .set on the model?  I think if might have to do with the render functionality I've put in...

Backbone View:

```
    App.Views.PanelOne = Backbone.View.extend({


    initialize: function() {
        console.log("View PanelOne Initialized");

        panelonesetting = this.model.get('panel_one');
        console.log( panelonesetting );

        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);

    },

    render: function(){
        if ( panelonesetting == "poolprice" ){
            this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/poolprice']({}));
        return this;
        };
        if ( panelonesetting == "none" ){
            this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/none']({}));
        return this;
        };
        if ( panelonesetting == "noconnection" ){
            this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/noconnection']({}));
        return this;
        };
    }


});
```

Backbone Router:

```
App.Routers.Dashboard = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        ""          : "index"       
        },

    initialize: function(options) {
    console.log("Router initialized");
      preflist = new App.Models.PrefList({});

    preflist.fetch({
        success: function() {
            console.log( preflist );
          paneloneview = new App.Views.PanelOne({ model: preflist });
          $('#panelone').html(paneloneview.render().$el);             
        }  
    });
  },

    index: function() {

    }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some accidental globals. In particular, you have this in your view's `initialize`:

```
panelonesetting = this.model.get('panel_one');
```

and then the `render` looks at `panelonesetting`. There is no `var` on that `panelonesetting` so it is a global variable.

The `initialize` method is called when you construct your view and it is never called again; that means that `panelonesetting` will be assigned the initial `panel_one` value and then it is never updated. So, if the model is changed, your `render` will be called but it will be looking at the original `panel_one` setting. The result is that nothing seems to change: you can call your `render` as many times as you want with whatever model changes you want and you'll never see anything happen.

You should be checking the value of `panel_one` inside your `render` method:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
},

render: function(){
    var panelonesetting = this.model.get('panel_one');
    if(panelonesetting == "poolprice")
        this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/poolprice']({}));
    if(panelonesetting == "none")
        this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/none']({}));
    if(panelonesetting == "noconnection")
        this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/noconnection']({}));
    return this;
}
```

Your `preflist and`paneloneview` variables in your router are also global when they should almost certainly be local.

Comment: You're right, it's now working!  YEAHHHHHHHH!  Thanks for the advice on the variables as well.

Comment: And you could probably use `this.$el.html(JST['dashboard/' + panelonesetting]({}));` if you trusted `panelonesetting` to make sense.

Comment: Wow!  Great suggestion!  My code's readability just escalated big-time!  Where is your virtual tips jar!?